# Is there a way to produce Kafka messages with headers using Kafka Confluent REST API?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-rest

I'm trying to send messages to Kafka with some custom headers, but I could't find a way to do it. According to the [documatation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/api.html#topics), The `POST /topics/(string: topic_name)` API does not have a way to attach custom headers to messages.

Does anyone know a way to send Kafka messages with custom headers through the confluent Kafka REST API?

Here is my sample request body I sent to the REST proxy

```
POST /topics/stream.mycustomtopic

{
    "records": [{
        "value": "{\"myFirstKey\":\"myFirstValue\"}"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, the REST Proxy does not currently support Kafka Headers. You would need to use the [Producer API](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html) to set the headers.

Comment: It's not supported by the REST Proxy. There's an open issue here https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest/issues/523 to track if you want.