# Http kafka proxy supporting message with headers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm looking for an http proxy for Kafka that supports posting messages with headers to a topic (the headers are for the message itself, not http headers)

The official http proxy from Confluent does not support it, is there alternative?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55036037/is-there-a-way-to-produce-kafka-messages-with-headers-using-kafka-confluent-rest

Comment: In fact I'm saying in the question that I'm looking for alternatives because I already know that the official proxy does not support it.

Comment: Looking for software is off topic for Stackoverflow anyway, unfortunately [help]

Comment: You could use NiFi `ListenHTTP`, then do anything with it, including `ProduceKafka`